# Flutter ThemeData Primary color not changing from theme when trying to add a primary color

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

Im following the BMI Calculator app from the London App Brewery on LinkedIn Learning.
when attempting to set the primaryColor to red, my emulator still shows the Light Blue default AppBar even though i am overriding the Primary Color. here's  the code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: const InputPage(),
    );
  }
}

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Body Text'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is still good !

You may pay attention on reinstalling your app or check if hot reload is working

Answer (score 25):

I am also attending same training from LondonAppBrewery. This code fixed the problem.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: "BMI Calculator",
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    appBarTheme:AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff0a0e21),
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xff0a0e21),
  ),
  home: InputPage(),
);
```

Comment: thanks bro, same here following her course

Comment: This worked for me, but the course video is still not updated by the instructor. :(

Answer (score 22):

Use primarySwatch

```
theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.red,
  ),
```

Comment: How would you use a hex color?

Comment: check out this article on dev https://dev.to/rohanjsh/custom-swatch-for-material-app-theme-primaryswatch-3kic

Answer (score 15):

This issue has been pointed at flutter [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89839#issuecomment-919437144) page. They say

> We will eventually be moving all components away from ThemeData.primaryColor

So you can use

```
 theme: ThemeData(
     colorScheme: ColorScheme.light().copyWith(primary: Colors.red),
 );
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the following approach you can have full control over the individual properties in Themedata

```
class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        ),
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also figured out just like you guys answered above. However, in dark design there was a shadowColor missing, so I added it.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0a0e21),
      elevation: 5.0,
      shadowColor: Colors.black87,
    ),
    primaryColor: const Color(0xFF0A0E21),
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
      secondary: const Color(0xFF101427),
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0A0E21),
    ),
    home: const MainPage(),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm undergoing the same training program. As Mohtashim mentioned above, I tried to tweak the background app theme code and it worked as expected.

```
theme: ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF101427), //use your hex code here
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add default colors that provide by flutter you can change like this.

```
theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
    primarySwatch: Colors.red,
  ),
```

If you want to use custom colors, you can use like this

```
 static const Color primaryColor = Color(0xFF623CEA);

  static MaterialColor primaryColorSwatch = MaterialColor(
    primaryColor.value,
    const <int, Color>{
      50: Color(0xFF623CEA),
      100: Color(0xFF623CEA),
      200: Color(0xFF623CEA),
      300: Color(0xFF623CEA),
      400: Color(0xFF623CEA),
      500: Color(0xFF623CEA),
      600: Color(0xFF623CEA),
      700: Color(0xFF623CEA),
      800: Color(0xFF623CEA),
      900: Color(0xFF623CEA),
    },
  );

MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: primaryColor,
        primarySwatch: primaryColorSwatch,
      ),
      home: Demo(),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The most complete way to do it would be to set the [*colorScheme property*](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/colorScheme.html) inside [ThemeData()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html).

In the [*ColorScheme class*](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html) itself you can either decide to set manually all of the color groups, like so:

```
theme: ThemeData(
   colorScheme: ColorScheme(
       brightness: Brightness.light,
       primary: Colors.red,
       onPrimary: Colors.white,
       secondary: Colors.green,
       onSecondary: Colors.white,
       error: Colors.yellow,
       onError: Colors.black,
       background: Colors.white,
       onBackground: Colors.black,
       surface: Colors.grey,
       onSurface: Colors.black,
   ),
),
```

Or you can decide to use the [*ColorScheme.fromSwatch() constructor*](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme/ColorScheme.fromSwatch.html) to create a swatch:

```
theme: ThemeData(
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
    primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    accentColor: Colors.amber,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: false,
```

Make this false - useMaterial3: false,

*Make this false - useMaterial3: false
*I had an issue where I was not able to change color inside "theme: *ThemeData(
*primaryColor: Color(0xff24386e),
*primarySwatch: MaterialColor(
*----
*----

*it was started because of a flutter (3.13.0-7.0.pre.46 ), OS (16.5.1) of *IOS and OS (13.4.1 (c)) of Macbook which I upgrade to the latest.

*I am using Dart 3.1.0*

Answer (score 0):

```
theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0D22),
      ),
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already four other answers that have been submitted. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of different capabilities? E.g., why do you prefer `colorScheme` over `primarySwatch`?

Answer (score 0):

U can Use :

```
    theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for changing app bar color worked for me,replace the color code as per ur need

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        ),
        accentColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light()
              .copyWith(primary: Colors.red, secondary: Colors.red))),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
class BMICalculator extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Color(0xff0a0e21))),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So for hex color, we need to use MaterialColor() of primarySwatch. And for Material color, there are two arguments required, hex color and Map data for the shades of the color.
First create a Map variable, color, outside the stateless widget:

```
Map<int, Color> color =
{
  50:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .1),
  100:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .2),
  200:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .3),
  300:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .4),
  400:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .5),
  500:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .6),
  600:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .7),
  700:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .8),
  800:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, .9),
  900:Color.fromRGBO(136,14,79, 1),
};
```

And then:
primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xFF0A0E21,color),

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

also, you can try colorScheme

```
 theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Colors.red,
          secondary: Colors.purple,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: const Color(0xFF0A0E21))
```

This is updated snippet for using primary color

Answer (score -1):

I follow the same course. This is the code that helped me. Also thank you guys for answering the questions above. I nearly pulled out my hair. If anyone knows why flutter changes and deprecates syntax so dramatically please explain. It would be nice to know.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff0a0e21),
        ),
        primaryColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF0A0E21),
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
          secondary: Colors.purple,
        ),
      ),
      home: InputPage(),
    );
  }
}
```